# Strange value comparison issue in Kotlin, "===" returns true but "==" returns false

Tags: android, kotlin, equals, equality

I have encountered a very strange value comparison issue in Kotlin that I cannot explain, the following code prints **false**

```
data class Foo (
    val a: Byte
)
fun main() {
    val NUM: Byte = 1
    var m: Foo? = Foo(NUM)
    println(m?.a == NUM)
}
```

But if I change the last line to

```
println(m?.a === NUM)
```

or

```
println(m!!.a == NUM)
```

it prints **true**, I'm so confused, anyone could help to explain? Thanks.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this in an Android Studio kotlin scratchfile. All three of these print statements print true for me.

Comment: I think you're mistaken. Your original code should also print true. Side note... the `===` identity equality operator is generally not useful with numbers because the Number classes don't have stable identities.

Comment: Interesting, for me the first case prints false in Android Studio, also in a kotlin playground: https://play.kotlinlang.org/#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS4zLjcwIiwicGxhdGZvcm0iOiJqYXZhIiwiYXJncyI6IiIsImpzQ29kZSI6IiIsIm5vbmVNYXJrZXJzIjp0cnVlLCJ0aGVtZSI6ImlkZWEiLCJjb2RlIjoiZGF0YSBjbGFzcyBGb28gKFxuICAgIHZhbCBhOiBCeXRlXG4pXG5mdW4gbWFpbigpIHtcbiAgICB2YWwgTlVNOiBCeXRlID0gMVxuICAgIHZhciBtOiBGb28/ID0gRm9vKE5VTSlcbiAgICBwcmludGxuKG0/LmEgPT0gTlVNKVxufSJ9, could you have a try @Matt, @Tenfour04?

Comment: @XiaoyuYu I can reproduce it in the kotlin playground. Very interesting. I don't have an answer for you, but I'm guessing it's related to how nullables are implemented in kotlin. The strange behavior goes away if you change `m` to a non-nullable.

Comment: @whitehills note that in my case === evaluates to true, while == evaluates to false, which is the opposite case.

Comment: Weird, I reproduced it too. Ints and Longs are unaffected. And if you assign `m?.a` to a variable and then compare that, you get true as expected.

Comment: Oh, this is interesting. So it seems like a bug introduced in 1.5.20 (?). The reason why people couldn't reproduce it locally is probably because they didn't use the latest Kotlin version. I can reproduce it with 1.5.20.

Comment: I agree with you - this seems to be a bug in 1.5.20. I opened an issue at jetbrains: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-47717. Let's see what happens :)

Comment: https://pl.kotl.in/ojFyfOCwh

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue only appears in version 1.5.20, while 1.5.10 is not affected.

This seems to be an issue in the newer kotlin compiler version.

With some bytecode, we can explain the problem (`data class` was called `Blah`, `func` was called `blah`).

This is the bytecode, compiled with 1.5.10, that returns `True` for `println(m?.a == NUM)` - everything seems to be fine. We're doing a primitive not equals of the two numbers, which returns `False` (correct since `1 != 1` is `False`).

```
Compiled from "WtfTest.kt"
public final class de.sfxr.WtfTest {
  public de.sfxr.WtfTest();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #8                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public final void blah();
    Code:
       0: iconst_1
       1: istore_1
       2: new           #14                 // class de/sfxr/Blah
       5: dup
       6: iload_1
       7: invokespecial #17                 // Method de/sfxr/Blah."<init>":(B)V
      10: astore_2
      11: aload_2
      12: astore_3
      13: aload_3
      14: invokevirtual #21                 // Method de/sfxr/Blah.getA:()B
      17: iload_1
      18: istore_3
      19: iload_3
      // PRIMITIVE NOT EQUALS => False
      20: if_icmpne     27                  
      23: iconst_1
      24: goto          28
      27: iconst_0
      28: istore_3
      29: iconst_0
      30: istore        4
      32: getstatic     #27                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      35: iload_3
      36: invokevirtual #33                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Z)V
      39: return
}
```

However in Version 1.5.20, the bytecode instructs for an object comparison using the JVMs `Intrinsics.areEqual` on a boxed `Integer` with content `1` and a boxed `Byte` with content `1`, which will return `False`, since it uses `equals` on `Byte`. This is the cause of this issue. The compiler devs surely wanted a `True` at this point.

But why does this evaluate to false? Here's a snippet of the `Byte.equals`'s description "The result is true if and only if the argument is not null **and is a Byte object** that contains the same byte value as this object."

...and the bytecode for explaination:

```
Compiled from "WtfTest.kt"
public final class de.sfxr.WtfTest {
  public de.sfxr.WtfTest();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #8                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public final void blah();
    Code:
       0: iconst_1
       1: istore_1
       2: new           #14                 // class de/sfxr/Blah
       5: dup
       6: iload_1
       7: invokespecial #17                 // Method de/sfxr/Blah."<init>":(B)V
      10: astore_2
      11: aload_2
      12: astore_3
      13: aload_3
      14: invokevirtual #21                 // Method de/sfxr/Blah.getA:()B
      17: invokestatic  #27                 // Method java/lang/Byte.valueOf:(B)Ljava/lang/Byte;
      20: iload_1
      21: invokestatic  #32                 // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
      // OBJECT COMPARISON VIA JVM ON BOXED BYTE(1) AND BOXED INT(1) => False
      24: invokestatic  #38                 // Method kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics.areEqual:(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Z    
      27: istore_3
      28: iconst_0
      29: istore        4
      31: getstatic     #44                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      34: iload_3
      35: invokevirtual #50                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Z)V
      38: return
}
```

### UPDATE

The guys from jetbrains commented the issued ticket https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-47717 with "That's definitely a bug." and priority major.

Comment: worth to file a bug ticket for it? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT

Comment: @Simulant already done https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-47717